# How to show that each factor of a product space is homeomorphic to a subspace of the product

Tags: general-topology

Let be $\mathfrak{X}=\{(X_j,\mathcal{T}_j):j\in J\}$ a collection of topological not empty spaces and we consider the product space $\Pi_{j\in J}X_j$. Well using the Choice Axiom for any $i\in J$ we can define for some fixed $z\in\Pi_{j\in J}X_j$ the set 
$$
Z_i=\{x\in\Pi_{j\in J}: x(j)=z(j), j\neq i \land x(j)=x_h\in X_i, j=i\}_{h\in|X_i|}
$$ 
and we prove that it is homeomorphic to $X_i$. So we consider the restriction $\pi_i|_{Z_i}$ of the projection $\pi_i$ and we observe that by a previous theorem it is continuous on the subspace topology $\mathcal{T}_Z$ of $Z$; moreover since two elements $x$ and $y$ of $Z_i$ differ only for their values $x(i)$ and $y(i)$ it result that $\pi_i|_{Z_i}$ is bijective and so it is that 
$$
\forall A\in\mathcal{T}:\pi_i|_{Z_i}(A\cap Z_i)=\pi_i|_{Z_i}(A)\cap\pi_i|_{Z_i}(Z_i)=\pi_i(A)\cap X_i=\pi_i(A)\in\mathcal{T}_i
$$
from which we can colude that $\pi_i|_{Z_i}$ is open and so it is a homeomorphism between $Y_i$ and $X_i$.

Well I doubt that the prove of the "openness" of $\pi_i|_{Z_i}$ is uncorrect, since it would result that $\pi_i|_{Z_i}(A\cap Z_i)=\pi_i|_{Z_i}(A)\cap\pi_i|_{Z_i}(Z_i)\neq\pi_i(A)\cap X_i$; but anyway I am sure that the proof is generally okay, since the same procedure is indicated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328025/each-factor-space-is-homeomorphic-to-the-subspace-of-the-product) by the professor Brian M. Scott. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just gave the full argument in the first part of [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3558988/4280) where I think you got the question as a spin-off, as it were.

You don't need to define $Z_j$, just define an embedding $e$ and show its continuous, 1-1 and has a continuous inverse. Openness of $e$ follows (between $X_j$ and its image) automatically.

Comment: Dear Professor Brandsma,
I warmly thank you for reading the message I had left in the comments [section] and also for replying in a short time: I am a young enrolled on an Engineering course and unfortunately I need to teach myself Topology, so I let you imagine how useful your rigorous explanations are to me. Thank you!!! 

P.S.
If during the study of the next pages I'll find other difficulties, could I venture to ask for your help again?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro post questions, I'll see if I have time to help.. Always glad to, of course, or I wouldn't be here...

Comment: Thanks! See you soon!!